# Determining the minimum degree if $δ(G) \leq k, k \in N^* $

Tags: graph-theory

Let be $G = (V,E)$ a graph with $n$ nodes and $δ(G)  \leq k, k \in N^* $.
Describe an algorithm with complexity $O (n) $ for determining the minimum degree of this graph.

Please help with some hints or solutions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Def. 1:** Let $G=(V,E)$ with incidence mapping $p$ where $V=\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a graph. The $n \times n$ matrix $A(G)=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,\cdots,n}$ defined by
$$a_{ij}:=|\{e \in E\ |\ p(e)=(x_i,x_j) \}|$$
is called the adjacency matrix of $G$.

If $A(G)$ is symmetric, then $G$ is undirected. If $G$ is simple, i.e. no multiple edges, then we can define $A(G)$ by
$$a_{ij} := 
     \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1, & \text{if } (x_i,x_j) \in E, \\
         0, & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right. 
  $$

**Proposition 1:** $\forall x_i \in V$ with $A(G)=(a_{ij})_{i,j\in|V|=n}$, we have
$$indeg(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}$$

$$outdeg(x_i)= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}$$

whereby $indeg$ is the in-degree and $outdeg$ is the outdegree. In the symmetric case, we of course have

$$deg(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}$$

**Hint:** Now, implement an algorithm building the degree sequence of a given graph using its adjacency matrix. What is its running time complexity?